# Virtual machine not meeting Windows 11 system requirements, even though it should

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I am trying to create a Windows 11 virtual machine on Hyper-V. I downloaded a clean x64 ISO from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). Here is my attempt using Generation 2 as a commenter recommended:

- Generation 2
- Default Switch
- 8192 RAM
- 128 GB hard drive
- UEFI Secure boot enabled
- TPM enabled
- DirectX 12 enabled

However, when I start the virtual machine, I get the following message:

[image: Unable to boot]

I was able to get further using a Generation 1 virtual machine, before a commenter pointed out Windows 11 isn't supported in Generation 1. During those earlier Hyper-V new virtual machine setup wizard, I selected:

- Generation 1
- Default Switch
- 8192 RAM
- 128 GB hard drive

[image: vm summary]

I can connect to the virtual machine and upon starting it the Windows installation kicks off normally. However, the installation process stops, stating that the machine doesn't meet the system requirements:

[image: requirements message]

[As far as I can tell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications?r=1), Windows 11 only requires 4096 RAM and 64 GB hard drive, which the VM meets. My host processor is also well above the requirement:

[image: system processor]

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this message during installation? Thanks for any help!

[Edit] Here is my attempt to verify some additional requirements mentioned by commenters.

- TPM. Following Option 2 of [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-tpm-2-0-on-your-pc-1fd5a332-360d-4f46-a1e7-ae6b0c90645c) I was able to see this screen:

[image: TPM]

I don't know exactly what TPM is, but that seems to indicate the host machine has it enabled.

- DirectX 12 Graphics card. This was fairly easy to verify using [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/checking-your-version-of-directx-7b71e74f-02e8-456f-72c7-9a1c1bbf0e9a):

[image: DirectX version]

- UEFI Secure Boot. Using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/you-need-to-enable-secure-boot-windows), I was able to verify UEFI Secure Boot is enabled:

[image: UEFI Boot]

This seems to suggest all requirements are met.

Comment: When you click on the link in the dialog, it displays the requirements.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications. TPM and UEFI SecureBoot are *required*.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what those requirements were or how to verify them. I searched how to verify those settings and added the verification to my original question.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 11 isn't supported as a Generation 1 guest. You need to create it as a Generation 2 guest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realized that Window 11 isn't supported with the Generation 1 option. However, when I attempt Generation 2, I get an error message upon starting the machine indicating that there was no bootable media found. I've updated the original question with this additional information.

Answer (score 3):

You mention RAM and disk space. However, [the requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-system-requirements-86c11283-ea52-4782-9efd-7674389a7ba3) list some more items:

- TPM
- UEFI boot
- DirectX 12 Graphics card
- Secure boot

You don't mention any of these items, which leads me to believe you haven't really checked the URL the error message provides.

Comment: That's a rather rude way to observe my lack of knowledge, but I appreciate you pointing out the additional requirements. I did read the URL the error message provided, I just didn't understand how to verify all of the requirements listed. I'm updated the question with my attempts to verify these additional requirements.

Comment: "That's a rather rude way to observe my lack of knowledge" - no. He is directly indicating your lack of READING. The hardware requirements of Windows 11.

Comment: Wow, so this is one of those kinds of communities. Good to know. As stated, I read them, I just didn't know how to verify them all. I've literally never done this before.

Comment: @Jason I'd say it's at least a site that expects people to google `windows 11 Hyper-V requirements` before asking.

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks again for displaying the same rudeness I previously mentioned. I did Google it. I even linked it in my original post behind the text "As far as I can tell". That you mistook my ignorance for laziness and deception is exactly how you are being rude.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @joeqwerty I started using the Generation 2 setup option instead of Generation 1. I was getting an error booting, but that was because the Generation 2 setup assumes the ISO is on a DVD and not on a hard drive, requiring me to "press any key" when prompted to boot from DVD.

After in the Windows 11 setup, I was still getting the "requirements not met" error, however. Using another site where people are actually helpful, I was able to learn what I was doing wrong.

I had assumed that UEFI Secure Boot requirements were for the host machine. I didn't realize those were additional settings needed for the virtual machine after completing the new virtual machine setup wizard.

Someone explained that after creating the VM, I had to go into the security settings to enable these features (read-only because my VM was running when I took the screenshot):

[image: VM settings]

Posting here in case another VM newbie has the same misunderstanding.